# MySQL: Why my query can't finish?

Tags: mysql

I don't know why the query I've wroten, doesn't give me any output and just can't finish. Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8656d2/1 is the sample of my database, in real I have there about 260k records(rows). So you can see that query works with that table in the link, but in my whole database something is wrong. I waited almost 30 minutes for any results, but the query process is interminably. I don't know what should I do now, what can be the reason of described problem?

Comment: Just try using limit like `limit 1000` then `10000`

Comment: And you have to optimized your query.

Comment: you have no indexes and you are basically calling a routine 260k times in a row...  of course it's going to be slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't actually know why the query isn't completing on your MySQL with 260K records.  But I can speculate that the correlated subquery you have in the `SELECT` statement is the culprit.  Let's look closely at that guy:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(MAX(EVENT_TIME), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
FROM my_table mt
WHERE
    EVENT_TYPE = '2' AND
    mt.ID = my_table.ID
```

You are basically telling MySQL to do a `MAX()` calculation across the *entire* table, for *every* record in your `my_table` table.  Note that because the subquery is correlated, it might have to be run fresh for literally all 260K records.  Hopefully you can see that 260K x 260K operations would be a bit slow.

If I be correct, then a possible fix would be to rephrase your query using a join to a subquery table which finds the max event times for each `ID` in your table.  This query would be run once, and only once, and then it would be up to MySQL to find an efficient way to join back to your original table.  But in any case, this approach should be eons faster than what you were using.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM my_table t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID, MAX(EVENT_TIME) AS max_event_time
    FROM my_table
    WHERE EVENT_TYPE = '2'
    GROUP BY ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND
       t1.EVENT_TIME BETWEEN
           DATE_SUB(t2.max_event_time, INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND
           t2.max_event_time
WHERE t1.EVENT_TYPE != 3
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

Here is link to your updated Fiddle:

## Demo

Comment: Thank you for good explaining this problem. But I'm confused with one issue. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e910c/1 Here I added one row, which date is later than the date from event_type = 2 for ID = 0, so it shouldn't be in my output. How can I cope with this now? I would like to have in the output events with dates 12 hours or less earlier than the date from event_type=2 for each ID separately.

Comment: @JeffTheKiller I think I fixed the query as you want it.  Note that for those `ID` whose most recent event has nothing else within 12 hours of it, your query is still returning those individual events.  If this _isn't_ what you expect, then my advice to you would be to update your question and show sample along with output, with a clear explanation.